# RegExp to strip a variable in ES6-like format

Tags: javascript, regex, regexp-replace

I'm using an ES6-like variable formatting with the syntax of `${varName}`, and while processing them I'm trying to enumerate all unique variables specified, using the following code:

```
function enumVars(txt) {
    var v, names = [];
    var reg = /\$\{\s*[a-zA-Z\$_][a-zA-Z0-9\$_]*\s*}/g;
    while (v = reg.exec(txt)) {
        var svn = v[0].replace(/???/, ''); // stripped variable name;
        if (names.indexOf(svn) === -1) {
            names.push(svn);
        }
    }
    return names;
}
```

I haven't been able to figure out the correct `RegExp` for stripping the variable name from the `exec` result.

When I use `v[0]`, it gives me `${varName}` string, and I need to strip it into just `varName`, removing leading `${`, trailing `}`, and all white spaces that may reside inside `{  }` around the variable.

The variable is expected to follow the javascript naming convention, which means:

- a valid variable starts with a letter, underscore or '$' symbol, followed by any combination of letters, digits, underscores or '$';
- leading and trailing spaces around the variable are to be ignored.

In all, we may have a variable returned from `exec` as `${  _$abc12_$  }`, and I need a RegExp for calling `replace` that would return just `_$abc12_$`.

Thanks everyone for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your replace regexp could be

```
/^\$\{\s*|\s*}$/g
```

In English, this says "remove both `${...` at the beginning, or `...}` at the end.

It could be slightly easier to just grab all the strings, and transform them all at once, then filter out duplicates:

```
function enumVars(txt) {
    return txt

        // Find all matches of form ${var}
        . match(/\$\{\s*[a-z$_][a-z0-9$_]*\s*}/gi)

        // Strip off ${ and }, yielding just variable name
        . map(function(v) { return v.replace( /^\$\{\s*|\s*}$/g, ''); })

        // Filter out duplicates
        . filter(function(v, i, a) { return a.indexOf(v) === i; });
}
```

Comment: This seems to work, thank you! As for the English, for the very least, I couldn't skip the part explaining what the variable can be made of, because this does affect the answer.

Comment: Following your changes, I must say that I had to change `\}` to just `}`, and that the alternative `enumVars` doesn't work for me. First, it is missing `)` to close the `map` call, and then it goes - `what's uniq`? :) Other than that it looks very neat, I just fish it worked :)

Comment: I have made the changes I described earlier, except for the `uniq()` part, which throws an error. Please change it to make work.

Comment: The update does look slicker than my implementation, though perhaps they are the same. Just good to know a pure Reg-Ex approach for full measure. Cheers! Still, your top reg-ex has redundant \ in the end as \} ;)